# Is there any way to filter out my results on the basis of some string using scrapy, python?

Tags: python

I am scraping a site. I want title, author, description and tags. the name of author is given like "by Elbert" or "Elbert (author)" but I only want the author name, not the "by" or "(author)" which is written in the div of author

I am not sure about how to do this, I searched on the internet but could not find the solution to my problem.

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
def parse(self, response):
    with open('quotes-data.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar="'")

        csv_writer.writerow(['title', 'author', 'description', 'tags'])
        i = 1
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="book"]'):
            title  =  quote.xpath('./div[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first()
            author = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first()
            description =  quote.xpath('.//div[@class="description"]/text()').extract_first()
            tags = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="keywords"]/span[@class="tag"]/text()').extract()
            tags = ' '.join(tags)
            tags = f'\"{tags}\"'
            author = f'\"{author}\"'
            description = f'\"{description}\"'
            row = [i, author, title, description, tags]
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

            i += 1

            yield {
                'title': title,
                'author': author,
                'tags': tags,
                'description': description
            }
```

I want only the name of the Author.

Comment: Why not just use `.replace('by ', '').replace('(author)', '')` or `re.sub` for such cases? This question is not about `scrapy`.

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only types of formatting that you want to clean, something like this can work:

```py
def cleanAuthor(author):
    if 'by ' in author:
        return ' '.join(author.split()[1:])
    elif '(author)' in author:
        return author.replace('(author)', '').strip()

print(cleanAuthor('by Elbert'))
# >> Elbert
print(cleanAuthor('Elbert (author)'))
# >> Elbert
print(cleanAuthor('Elbert Something (author)'))
# >> Elbert Something
print(cleanAuthor('by Elbert Something'))
# >> Elbert Something
```

Comment: Add space to `if 'by' in author`, because otherwise you will be splitting names of authors, containing `by`.

Comment: @Shuvojit i didn't tried this. because my existed code could be affected. I tried.replace('by ', '') and .replace('(author)', '') and it worked.